# a matrix that gives a count of total orders where a basket of goods is there

Tags: python, pandas, matrix, count, e-commerce

Details about data

**Order Id**: order id is generated when a customer orders anything
**product** is the items that she is ordering

I want a count matrix wherein how many orders lemon and apple combination was, their input data is
[image]

I tried `groupby`

```
.groupby(\['product', 'order_id'\]).size().unstack(fill_value=0))
```

I am expecting the results to be

[image]

Comment: maybe you are searching for the `count` aggregation function? if thats not the case could you please provide a minimal input data example.

Comment: what is the difference between input and output? also where are the lemons? Seems like a poorly crafted question to me

Comment: input is order_id product
7930060 Lemon
7930060 Apple
7930060 Strawberry
7930060 Guava
7703566 Lemon
7703566 Apple
7703566 Banana
2703598 Lemon
2703598 Apple
2703598 Rose
2703598 Strawberry   and output I am expecting  Lemon Apple Strawberry Guava Banana Rose
Lemon 3 3 2 1 1 1
Apple 3 3 2 1 1 1
Strawberry 2 2 2 0 0 1
Guava 0 1 1 1 0 0
Banana 1 1 0 0 1 0
Rose 1 1 1 0 0 1